# column selection for over 10,000 lines in sublime windows

Tags: sublimetext2

I was trying to do a column (or vertical) selection in sublime but for over a 10,000 lines.

What happens with ctrl + shift and right click is that it takes to long to reach 10,000 lines. The same happens with ctrl+alt [up or down arrows].

I have found many topics on column selection but they are not efficient for a lot of lines.

Do you know how to select a column of more than 10,000 lines, in a fast way?

Comment: Do you have a question, or you just wanted to share your experience?

Comment: Have you tried ctrl + a? (Select all)

Comment: I updated the question thanks for the prompt "response"...

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the Split Selection Into Lines feature. Which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

First select all lines with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Then use the above shortcut to split your selection.